# Inspecting elements of an inductive type from OCaml

Tags: ocaml, coq

I would like to write a Coq plugin which would take an element of an inductive type and recursively pattern match on the element and preform some computation in each iteration. This sounds like a quite straight forward thing to do, but I don't really know where to start.

I have managed to find some Coq plugins, compile them and run them. But I have not found any kind of overview of Coq API to a get idea of basic concepts.

Useful resources I have found so far:

- [A small tutorial for Ocaml plugins to extend the Coq system](https://project.inria.fr/coqexchange/a-small-tutorial-for-ocaml-plugins-to-extend-the-coq-system/)
- [Emancipate yourself from LTac: Your first Coq plugin](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/your-first-coq-plugin/)

---

*Simple example:*

Let's have a simple inductive type representing expressions with a single binary operation

```
Inductive expr : Type :=
| var : nat  -> expr
| op  : expr -> expr -> expr
```

I would like to define a new Vernacular command `InspectExpression` which will recursively go over the expression and preform some computation.

```
InspectExpression (op (op (var 0) (var 1)) (var 2)). (* expression: "(x+y)+z" *)
```

My ultimate goal is to generate some C++ code based on these expressions, but I don't think that is important for the question/answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical source these days is the official [Coq Plugin Tutorial](https://github.com/coq/coq/tree/master/doc/plugin_tutorial) which while up-to-date, needs some help both with Google fu [so it appears first in searches] and with formatting / presentation.

I'd say start there, and don't hesitate to open bugs in the [Coq issue tracker](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues) if you would like to get some other kind of examples included.

[Coq's discourse](https://coq.discourse.group/) and [Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/coq/coq) are also very useful devices for plugin developers.

Comment: This is the first time I'm seeing the Coq Plugin Tutorial, despite the fact that I have spent quite some time googling for stuff like that. There should be a link to it on the doc page https://coq.inria.fr/documentation

Comment: Indeed @tom, please don't hesitate to report a bug about problems with the documentation, we will be very happy to improve it.